# Return a preferred root from the square root of a function

Tags: c, square-root

I am trying to solve the following equation for a special case, where l=b=0; and it should return a square root of a perfect square function e.g. sqrt((x-d)^2). This can have two solutions, (x-d) or (d-x). I would like to obtain (x-d) as my final solution, but the program by default returns (d-x) solution. I tried changing positions of d and x, but nothing seems to work. Here is my program :

```
float y(float x) {
  float l=0., b=0., d=8.5, r_0=3., z_0=0.1;
  return exp(-pow(x*x*cos(b*PI/180.)*cos(b*PI/180.)+d*d-2*d*x*cos(b*PI/180.)*cos(l*PI/180.), 0.5)/r_0)*exp(-x*pow(1-cos(b*PI/180.)*cos(b*PI/180.),0.5)/z_0) ;
}
int main(){
  FILE* fp =NULL;
  float x0,xn,step,s,int_val, tau; /* s = distance to the star from the sun*/

  int i,n, j ;
  scanf("%f%f%d",&x0,&xn,&n);
  step = (xn-x0)/n;
  s = y(x0) + y(xn);
  fp = fopen("trap.txt", "w");
  for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    s += 2*y(x0+i*step);
    fprintf(fp,"%e\n",s*step/2);
  }
  fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Is there some code missing?

Comment: That exponential has at least one optimization possible, i.e., `1-cos^2(x)=sin^2(x)`, etc.  Also, any reason you can't just take the negative branch instead?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking for the part:

```
-pow( x*x*cos( b*PI / 180. )*cos( b*PI / 180. ) + d*d - 2 * d*x*cos( b*PI / 180. )*cos( l*PI / 180. ), 0.5 )
```

First things first, there actually is a function `double sqrt( double x )` which is for calculating square roots.

The second thing is, hand in hand with the mathematics, `sqrt( square( anything ) )` will return `absolutevalue( anything )`. In your example case, `sqrt( (x-d)^2 )` will be equivalent to `absolutevalue( x-d )`. Since `absolutevalue( x-d )` is equal to `absolutevalue( d-x )`, changing the places of the values won't change anything...

If `x > d`, then it will evaluate to `x - d`; otherwise to `d - x`, that's what mathematics says.

Not with changing places, but you can simply put a minus sign before the whole `sqrt( square( ) )` thing to have their places changed. You already have one minus there, you can simply remove that.

With the knowledge that square root of a square evaluates to the absolute value, you also can replace that specific extract I wrote above with `fabs( x * cos( b * PI / 180. ) - d )`, where `fabs` is the function that takes absolute value of a `double`, and is defined in `math.h`.

Comment: Simplification to `fabs( x * cos( b * PI / 180. ) - d )` works because `l` is `0.0`?

Comment: If `l == b`, but `cos( l*PI / 180. ) != 1.0`, the formula does not simplify to `fabs( x * cos( b * PI / 180. ) - d )`.

Answer (score 0):

Use substitutions to replace repetitive terms.  With select constants, simplify.

```
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

float y(float x) {
  float l=0., b=0., d=8.5, r_0=3., z_0=0.1;
  double y;
  // y = exp(-pow(x*x*cos(b*PI/180.)*cos(b*PI/180.)+d*d-2*d*x*cos(b*PI/180.)*cos(l*PI/180.), 0.5)/r_0)
  // y *= exp(-x*pow(1-cos(b*PI/180.)*cos(b*PI/180.),0.5)/z_0);
  if (l != 0.0 || b != 0.0) {
    double xcosb = x*cos(b*PI/180.);
    double xsinb = x*sin(b*PI/180.);
    double  cosl =   cos(l*PI/180.);
    // general solution
    y = exp(-sqrt(xcosb*xcosb - 2*xcosb*d*cosl + d*d)/r_0);
    y *= exp(-xsinb/z_0);  // @abiessu
  } else {
    // y = exp(-sqrt(x*x - 2*x*d*1.0 + d*d)/r_0);
    // y *= exp(-0/z_0);
    // y = exp(-sqrt((x-d)*(x-d))/r_0);
    // y *= 1.0;
    y = exp(-fabs(x - d))/r_0;
  }
  return y;
}
```

This does obtain `(x-d)` as the final solution.  Suggest OP review the function for correctness.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.